# How to Access WinUI Generic.xaml file?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui

How can I access the generic.xaml file for winui 2.6?
In some controls, Microsoft has used the following brushes

```
CardStrokeColorDefaultBrush
CardBackgroundFillColorDefaultBrush
```

I found the following files

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.19041.0\Generic

generic.xaml
themeresource.xaml
```

but These brushes are not available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the `CommonStyles` used by WinUI on Github, at https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/CommonStyles/Common_themeresources_any.xaml.